# Appending objects to an array in a while loop overwrites previous elements

Tags: php, arrays, object, mysqli

StackOverflow, first question here. I'm trying to learn PHP with MySQL and I had a problem with arrays and objects.

Here's what I would like to happen.

```
Category object {
    [details] => Array (
        [category] => Desktop
        [notes] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    )

[properties] => Array (
    [0] => Property Object (
        [details] => Array (
            [property] => Hard Disk Size
            [category] => Desktop
            [notes] => 
        )
    )

    [1] => Property Object (
        [details] => Array (
            [property] => Memory Frequency
            [category] => Desktop
            [notes] => 
        )
    )

    [2] => Property Object (
        [details] => Array (
            [property] => Video Card Graphics Adapter
            [category] => Desktop
            [notes] => 
        )
    )
)
```

**But the result had all objects under the [properties] array hold the same value.**
(The value for properties[2] became the value of properties[0] and properties[1].)

I modified the code to push the details->property value of each object into the array and it worked as I would have liked. Only when pushing objects I have a problem.

Here's the code.

```
class Category {
    public static final function generate_template() {
        return array(
            "category" => null,
            "notes" => null
        );  
    }

    private static function query_category( $input_string ) {
        global $connection;

        $stmt = $connection->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category = ? LIMIT 1"
        );
        $stmt->bind_param( "s", $input_string );
        if ( !$stmt->execute() ) return false;   

        $category_details = Category::generate_template();

        $stmt->bind_result(
            $category_details["category"],
            $category_details["notes"]
        );
        $stmt->fetch();

        return $category_details;
    }

    private static function query_category_properties( $category ) {
        global $connection;

        $stmt = $connection->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE category = ?"
        );
        $stmt->bind_param( "s", $category );
        if ( !$stmt->execute() ) return false;

        $property_details = Property::generate_template();

        $stmt->bind_result(
            $property_details["property"],
            $property_details["category"],
            $property_details["notes"]
        );

        $properties_array;
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $properties_array[] = new Property( $property_details );
            // This caused the problem.
            // It works as expected when written like this.
            // $properties_array[] = (new Property( $property_details ))->details["property"];
        }

        return $properties_array;
    }

    // Object Things
    public $details;
    public $properties = null;

    public function __construct( $category ) {
        $this->details = Category::query_category( $category );
        $this->properties = Category::query_category_properties( $category );
    }
}

class Property {
    public static final function generate_template() {
        return array(
            "property" => null,
            "category" => null,
            "notes" => null
        );
    }

    public $details = array();

    public function __construct( $property_details ) {
        $this->details = $property_details;
    }
}

$category = new Category( "Desktop" );
print_r( $category );

?>
```

Here's what the code did.
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/uSsYNLzRIRfQihsSBrPeYylkcQ965Vs9TjyyIYz32Mf8suAO4y52w5JkMMMaj9D02pqEWVp9Rxs=w1332-h521

Here's what storing the properties of the code did.
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/xe5N2U6rGOlr3x4vh_Qm0CFRS8-7pDryn9FuSldyPXN5huRhBy31bqH1d7H4AS8phDcfunyp9OE=w1332-h521

(My reputation is not enough to post images. I just started here.)

**What I would like to do is to store those objects in an array but it doesn't seem to work.**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Please POST the relevant piece of code **here**

Comment: Added the code to the main body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better place your code right here.

Because using your link for example I found this:

```
$properties_array;
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $properties_array[] = 1; //(new Property( $property_details ))->details["property"];
        }
```

and I think it works fine except - it is commented the part you really want to debug. (maybe I am wrong)

but I think it must be:

```
$stmt->bind_result(
                $property_name,
                $property_category,
                $property_notes
            );
      $properties_array = array();
      while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $properties_array[] = array($property_name,$property_category,     $property_notes);
      }
```

sorry can't debug better for now, but if you said everything is fine - that should work.

Comment: Sorry, I made another copy of the script and I forgot that I'm working on the one I posted in here. You're correct. That's the one I wanted to debug. The correction you posted was the one that caused that problem. The commented part was just to remind myself that it works as expected if I used the string, not the object.

Comment: so could you post your real code in your question body? and explain what is wrong right now?

Comment: Just posted the code now. What's wrong is that when I push those objects into the array, all I get is multiple instances of the same object. (The last object is somewhat copied onto the previous elements of the array.)What I'm confused with is that when I create an array of strings, it's works fine. I get an array of different things. When I create an array of objects, it's all the same.

Comment: oh, I think I can understand what is going on. :-) Check my answer update. try to send referencies to array elements

Comment: It caused a fatal error. ( Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in C:\Users\Jason\Google Drive\Project Vigilum\includes\functions\categorization.php on line 44 )

Comment: $properties_array[] = new Property( array( $q_property, $q_category, $q_notes ) ); > This works. Should I not use arrays to bind results from a prepared statement?

Comment: yes, you can reread doc for bind_result . and there is no need to use your Property class anymore. just loose your cpu and memory resources

Comment: Okay, going to do that. Thanks again, by the way.